# Integrate ASP.NET MVC validation with Enterprise Library validation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

I am already using Enterprise Library 5 Validation for my model (which is used also in WCF methods), so I decided that I would like to avoid redundant validators from ASP.NET 4 MVC with DataAnnotations.

But it seems, Enterprise Library Validators are not picked up automatically by MVC.

if I use MVC DataAnnotations:

```
[RegularExpression(MyValidationExpressions.Email, ErrorMessage = MyValidationMessages.InvalidEmailMessage)]
public virtual string Email { get; set; }
```

HTML contains data-val-regex-pattern and the field is being validated client-side.

But if I use the existing EL based validation:

```
 [RegexValidator(MyValidationExpressions.Email, MessageTemplate = MyValidationMessages.EmptyFieldMessage))]
 public virtual string Email { get; set; }
```

it does not display validation errors client-side, and the generated HTML does not have any validation attributes.

What am I missing here, how do I force MVC to use the existing EL validators both client-side and server-side?

**Solution**:

I accepted the solution to move completely to DataAnnotations. It is the easiest way and it works fine with both EntLib 5 and MVC 4. But there is a little catch with ValidationFactory - I had to replace CreateValidatorFromAttributes with CreateValidator and specific flags. See this article for explanation about how DataAnnotations work with ValidationFactory:

[CreateValidatorFromAttributes doesn't use DataAnnotations Attributes](http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/30303)

Also DataAnnotations have the [Required] attribute which deals nicely with empty strings and strings which contain only spaces. There were some problems on VAB with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net MVC 2 Client validation implementation for Enterprise Library Validation Block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666954/asp-net-mvc-2-client-validation-implementation-for-enterprise-library-validation)

Comment: http://elvalweb.codeplex.com/

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619996/can-mvc-updatemodel-use-enterprise-library-vab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because VAB's `RegexValidatorAttribute` does not inherit from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute`, but directly from `ValidationAttribute`. Because of this MVC doesn't know how to handle it.

There is a way to change the way MVC does this handling, but I don't know how. But why don't you just replace the usage of the `RegexValidatorAttribute` with DataAnnotations' `RegularExpressionAttribute`? Validation Application Block 5 is able to handle DataAnnotations` attributes, so if the DataAnnotations attributes are working, just use them.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried your suggestion - DataAnnotations works fine instead of VAB, but there is a little catch with ValidationFactory - I had to replace CreateValidatorFromAttributes with CreateValidator and specific flags: http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/30303

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [`ModelValidatorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidatorprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for Enterprise Library validation. Brad Wilson has a [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/enterprise-library-validation-example-for-aspnet-mvc-2.html) describing how to do this.

However, it looks like this will only perform server side validation. If the attributes you are using are very similar to DataAnnotations, I would recommend using them instead.